# How can I decode ETH Input Data from txHash?

Tags: ethereum, evm, erc721

I am trying to decode the ETH Input Data, but tried few online tools it doesn't work.

I understand it required an ABI for the decode, I used ERC721 project Moonbirds for the testing below.

It is the transaction I am trying to decode:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5cf973e29fa4f624d3fe72786b678c54536ccb6e34c55d3602abc681fa326f5f

Through the etherscan api link I got the Input Data:

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionByHash&txhash=0x5cf973e29fa4f624d3fe72786b678c54536ccb6e34c55d3602abc681fa326f5f

`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":{"blockHash":"0x6d3a843b9727657409a36921f348a3d893867364b9e8b0c8fab48a58a1e125b8","blockNumber":"0xf08d35","from":"0x6cfdad0772edc2ea15076a9706ec7c1f0a791ac1","gas":"0x3a019","gasPrice":"0x315666e71","maxFeePerGas":"0x40d02c186","maxPriorityFeePerGas":"0x59682f00","hash":"0x5cf973e29fa4f624d3fe72786b678c54536ccb6e34c55d3602abc681fa326f5f","input":"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","nonce":"0x3d8","to":"0x74312363e45dcaba76c59ec49a7aa8a65a67eed3","transactionIndex":"0x44","value":"0x8cdc0b3916370000","type":"0x2","accessList":[],"chainId":"0x1","v":"0x1","r":"0x2d3fabec4c10c13e531443c5dfcbc905378f0f0d5d92f1994591f9600d2ea1b8","s":"0x5110925376eb9bfc7a763a2dd41fcd36754d87654e722f72fee8a9a59e114aac"}}`

So the Input Data is
`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`

And the ABI of Moonbirds contract I grabbed directly from etherscan as below:

`[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"name","type":"string"},{"internalType":"string","name":"symbol","type":"string"},{"internalType":"contract IERC721","name":"_proof","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address payable","name":"beneficiary","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address payable","name":"royaltyReceiver","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ApprovalCallerNotOwnerNorApproved","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ApprovalQueryForNonexistentToken","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ApprovalToCurrentOwner","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ApproveToCaller","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"BalanceQueryForZeroAddress","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"MintToZeroAddress","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"MintZeroQuantity","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"OwnerQueryForNonexistentToken","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"TransferCallerNotOwnerNorApproved","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"TransferFromIncorrectOwner","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"TransferToNonERC721ReceiverImplementer","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"TransferToZeroAddress","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"URIQueryForNonexistentToken","type":"error"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"approved","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"bool","name":"approved","type":"bool"}],"name":"ApprovalForAll","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Expelled","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Nested","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"Paused","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"buyer","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Refund","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"beneficiary","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"numPurchased","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Revenue","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"bytes32","name":"role","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"bytes32","name":"previousAdminRole","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"bytes32","name":"newAdminRole","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"RoleAdminChanged","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"bytes32","name":"role","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"}],"name":"RoleGranted","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"bytes32","name":"role","type":"bytes32"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"}],"name":"RoleRevoked","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Unnested","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"Unpaused","type":"event"},{"inputs":[],"name":"DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"EXPULSION_ROLE","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"signer","type":"address"}],"name":"addSigner","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"nonce","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"alreadyMinted","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"baseTokenURI","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"beneficiary","outputs":[{"internalType":"address payable","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"n","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"cost","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"expelFromNest","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getApproved","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"role","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"getRoleAdmin","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"role","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"index","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getRoleMember","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"role","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"getRoleMemberCount","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"role","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"grantRole","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"role","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"hasRole","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"}],"name":"isApprovedForAll","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"proofTokenIds","type":"uint256[]"}],"name":"mintPROOF","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"nonce","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"sig","type":"bytes"}],"name":"mintPublic","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"n","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mintUnclaimed","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"nestingOpen","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"nestingPeriod","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"nesting","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"current","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"total","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ownerOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"pause","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"paused","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"price","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"proof","outputs":[{"internalType":"contract IERC721","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"proofClaimsRemaining","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"proofMintingOpen","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"proofPoolRemaining","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"n","type":"uint256"}],"name":"purchaseFreeOfCharge","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"signer","type":"address"}],"name":"removeSigner","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renderingContract","outputs":[{"internalType":"contract ITokenURIGenerator","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"role","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"renounceRole","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"role","type":"bytes32"},{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"revokeRole","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_salePrice","type":"uint256"}],"name":"royaltyInfo","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"safeTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"safeTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"safeTransferWhileNesting","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"sellerConfig","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"totalInventory","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"maxPerAddress","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"maxPerTx","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint248","name":"freeQuota","type":"uint248"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"reserveFreeQuota","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"lockFreeQuota","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"lockTotalInventory","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approved","type":"bool"}],"name":"setApprovalForAll","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"_baseTokenURI","type":"string"}],"name":"setBaseTokenURI","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address payable","name":"_beneficiary","type":"address"}],"name":"setBeneficiary","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"open","type":"bool"}],"name":"setNestingOpen","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"open","type":"bool"}],"name":"setPROOFMintingOpen","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_price","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setPrice","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"contract ITokenURIGenerator","name":"_contract","type":"address"}],"name":"setRenderingContract","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"receiver","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint96","name":"feeBasisPoints","type":"uint96"}],"name":"setRoyaltyInfo","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"components":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"totalInventory","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"maxPerAddress","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"maxPerTx","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint248","name":"freeQuota","type":"uint248"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"reserveFreeQuota","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"lockFreeQuota","type":"bool"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"lockTotalInventory","type":"bool"}],"internalType":"struct Seller.SellerConfig","name":"config","type":"tuple"}],"name":"setSellerConfig","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"interfaceId","type":"bytes4"}],"name":"supportsInterface","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"tokenIds","type":"uint256[]"}],"name":"toggleNesting","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"tokenURI","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"totalSold","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"unpause","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"usedMessages","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]`

I put those information into below online decoder tools, but just Null return.

https://input-data-decoder-ethereum.ethorbit.com/

https://lab.miguelmota.com/ethereum-input-data-decoder/example/

Any steps I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I dig it out finally. The first 4 bytes of input data, i.e. 357a150b, refering to a function named "run()", it is not able to decode while using Moonbirds' contract ABI as the user trading the NFT with x2y2.

And x2y2 is using UUPS proxy contract, so it require to grab the ABI in that contract for the decode. Once it does, the input data will be showing:

```
{
  "method": "run",
  "types": [
    "(tuple[],tuple[],tuple,bytes32,bytes32,uint8)"
  ],
  "inputs": [
    [
      [
        [
          {
            "type": "BigNumber",
            "hex": "0x7454eb3e556814215da898e4cf5bce6d"
          },
          "0xc15AdD7Eb1BA708BC7189CEf6A4c47200b77a52b",
          {
            "type": "BigNumber",
            "hex": "0x01"
          },
          {
            "type": "BigNumber",
            "hex": "0x01"
          },
          {
            "type": "BigNumber",
            "hex": "0x01"
          },
          {
            "type": "BigNumber",
            "hex": "0x634cd87c"
          },
          "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
          "0x",
          [
            [
              {
                "type": "BigNumber",
                "hex": "0x945a825ca8ed0000"
              },
              "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000023581767a106ae21c074b2276d25e5c3e136a68b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000016af"
            ]
          ],
          "0xb6d8405bea70112a179b5e3adc9519bbecf9f0dc729ffd9d3b08a78d0ad64868",
          "0x6dc5ebf80dd7211d6fd0dbde475a9c15e0955a4d665013abf41fcb9449a51dbf",
          27,
          1
        ]
      ],
      [
        [
          1,
          {
            "type": "BigNumber",
            "hex": "0x00"
          },
          {
            "type": "BigNumber",
            "hex": "0x00"
          },
          {
            "type": "BigNumber",
            "hex": "0x945a825ca8ed0000"
          },
          "0xe2062adcc106c406c100caecd92ec2f460facad10c87ff99d3e86d5f3b4a1bc5",
          "0xF849de01B080aDC3A814FaBE1E2087475cF2E354",
          "0x",
          {
            "type": "BigNumber",
            "hex": "0x00"
          },
          {
            "type": "BigNumber",
            "hex": "0x00"
          },
          {
            "type": "BigNumber",
            "hex": "0x00"
          },
          []
        ]
      ],
      [
        {
          "type": "BigNumber",
          "hex": "0x01fd6b8e0139b0"
        },
        {
          "type": "BigNumber",
          "hex": "0x634ce4f5"
        },
        {
          "type": "BigNumber",
          "hex": "0x077e772392b60000"
        },
        {
          "type": "BigNumber",
          "hex": "0x00"
        },
        "0x6cFdad0772EDC2EA15076A9706ec7c1F0a791aC1",
        false
      ],
      "0xd63275e71697447cbfe85a27d9ecfc2569f85337def8375d777cfd93c5455b35",
      "0x2f405586c7559114dbe9e071a1410afd8bb7d2b3cdda3ef7bc77376d010e8f41",
      28
    ]
  ],
  "names": [
    [
      "input",
      [
        "orders",
        "details",
        "shared",
        "r",
        "s",
        "v"
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

But it is still a way to go to decode the trading data, e.g. the amount, the NFT #...etc.